# How to get image content url from google drive?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I want to select the image file from the google drive and when i select the image file, I want to get the content url of the image.

When I gone through the drive documentation, It is hard to identify the needed one. I also referred lots of other examples. Based on that I have coded like this.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    try {
        if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
                .setMimeType(new String[]{"image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/html"})
                .build(mGoogleApiClient);
        getActivity().startIntentSenderForResult(
                intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_OPENER, null, 0, 0, 0);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        Log.w("", "Unable to send intent", e);
    }
}
```

So when i select the image file, I will get redirect to onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        mFileId = (DriveId) data.getParcelableExtra(
                OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);
        String url = "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=" + mFileId.getResourceId();
    }
}
```

Here based on the file id am concatenating the file id with the url which is mentioned in the documentation.

I am getting the url like `https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B6cjR1AhhqLDTDdqdG0xdVB2aTg`

When i load this url in browser without login, it brings the image.

This is the image am not selected from the root folder.In root folder, I have created one folder and from that i have selected this image.

The problem is, when i pick image from the root folder am getting this url for one image `https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B5bAaaRm0Rq9TTBCRUx5VWRiU3NuYVV5NXdDTmkzclRGaGg0`

This url is asking the login permission.

When I load both image in browser, I am getting url like`https://doc-0g-2o-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/dm4h1t8p59kkqd9vovoeu6v6ncptndiv/jb05c9rgr3ko1ba5edb8uo4vf2c8gifj/............`

Can someone guide how to get this googleusercontent url for all the images?

Because once i loaded the image url which i selected from the root folder am getting the googleusercontent url. After that i logged out and again i tried with googleusercontent url. It is working. But I don't know how to get the googleusercontent url. Plese help to solve this problem.

Comment: Ever found any solution for this?